# Silverlight on ipad

Tags: silverlight, ipad

What are the current possibilities to run silverlight on the iPad please ?
Other than the video streaming MS demo of course.

If there's no official packages or something, I'm interested in hacks too

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this article:

http://www.machackpc.com/featured/flash-silverlight-on-ipadiphone-with-out-installing-any-apps-videos/

Also, perhaps you can give us more of an idea what you are trying to achieve with silverlight for a more detailed answer?

You should also bear in mind that the main issue is the support on the apple devices - a political decisions by Apple. There are ways and means to get the support unofficially, but I can vouch for them being flawed and as good as useless.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your answer. I checked out the link above and actually this solution is too young and not yet efficient at all, I was wondering if there was actually a solution that installs silverlight directly on the iPad, so avoiding the distributed rendering. I guess there's no way yet but well... Let's hope this will come soon

Comment: No bother, I'm sorry to advise that there is no silverlight support natively, primarily (as mentioned) for political reasons between Microsoft and Apple. I can't see any mention of this being in the pipeline either, which is obviously not ideal for you either. Sorry I couldn't deliver better news for you.

Comment: +1 for the link. Interesting idea... send input to another server running the Flash/Silverlight app and send the result back (as video?). For a typical Silverlight/Flash app the round-tripping must kill performance/interactivity. Not sure they will ever solve that. I prefer frames per second to seconds per frame :)

Answer (score 3):

NO. There isn't anything available right now...

Answer (score 1):

Try alternative solution.
With ABYTY Browser you can run any Flash and Silverlight apps for business and entertainment like on desktop.
For view Silverlight or Flash on your iPhone (iPad, iPod) you not need of jailbreaking it or installing any applications from the App Store or Cydia. You not need install flash player or silverlight on your iphone. Simply open link  [ABYTY Browser](http://www.abyty.com/browser) from iDevice and follow appeared instructions. At this moment it little bit ugly and not have sound, but working in basic on iPhone and iPod too.